# Please recommend a Mono (i.e. C#) audio reading library

Tags: c#, .net, audio, mono

I'm trying to write a small app that displays the contents of an audio file in the frequency domain.  I'm looking for a Mono-compatible library that can read an audio file and give me the contents in a physically meaningful way.  Can anyone make any recommendations?

Comment: What Audio Formats are you interested in reading? Just .wav or something else?

Comment: As many as possible, so long as the API works in a format-independent way.

Comment: I think you may need to break this question in to two pieces. One is for the reading of audio files such that you can get a consistent representation of the audio data and the other component is how you then can interpret the information that has been decoded. Otherwise you should consider the Banshee Source Code that has been mentioned because you would need to access these functions together.

Comment: I'm just asking for a library that will read the audio files.  So long as the representation is physically meaningful, I can do the interpretation myself.

Comment: So for all the clarifications; when you say Mono compatiable are you specifically looking for a libary which is cross platform and doesn't rely on windows Interop?

Comment: Not necessarily - I'd be satisfied with a windows-specific library so long as I could use it with mono to create a GTK# app.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from responses to my question [asked half a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896/how-can-i-play-compressed-sound-files-in-c-in-a-portable-way) there's currently no other way than to DllImport calls to some binary libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest maybe having a look at the [Banshee source code](http://banshee-project.org/download/).

As you probably know, Banshee is an open-source media library and player for Linux that runs on Mono. Chances are there's some source code you could use in there.

Answer (score 1):

Banshee uses the gtkstreamer library, there's a mono implementation called gtkstreamer#

this might help:

[How to build gstreamer-sharp with monodevelop/xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577733/how-to-build-gstreamer-sharp-with-monodevelop-xamarin)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the MonoMac bindings which include CoreAudio bindings on MacOS X.