# Audio library that can be used for Mono

Tags: c#, mono

I am working on speech recognition. I am quite new in this field. Can any one help me out that which audio library can be helpful for audio processing using C# on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There was a question on SO about audio reading library for Mono: [Please recommend a Mono (i.e. C#) audio reading library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023988/please-recommend-a-mono-i-e-c-audio-reading-library)

Also there is a .NET bindings for PortAudio library that you can try: https://code.google.com/p/portaudiosharp/