# How to build gstreamer 1.0 C# .Net bindings on Windows 7?

Tags: c#, git, mingw, building

I want to build gstreamer 1.0 C# .Net bindings (gstreamer-sharp-0.99.0 in particular) on Windows 7 from http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gstreamer-sharp/ . 
Using Git shell with minGw and command "./autogen.sh && make" results in failure. It says:

```
Can't locate Autom4te/ChannelDefs.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /mingw/share/autoconf 
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/prl5/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/msys 
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /c/MinGw/bin/
autoreconf-2.68 line 40. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /c/MinGW/bin/
autoreconf-2.68 line 40.
```

and

```
./autogen.sh: line 5: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

For now the best is to compile the managed parts on linux and compile the glue on Windows. See  [How to build gstreamer-sharp with monodevelop/xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577733/how-to-build-gstreamer-sharp-with-monodevelop-xamarin/21607884#21607884) for a solution

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I can't build https://github.com/Vocaluxe/Vocaluxe/ project can you please take a look at my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672249/building-vocaluxe-on-windows-using-visual-studio-2012-or-xamarin-studio ?

Comment: Darkice, I want to ask you whether is it possible to run gstreamer-sharp bindings on .Net C# particularly?

Comment: gstreamer-sharp runs fine on .NET + Windows

Comment: How can I import the libraries required for gstreamer C# 1.0? When I try to add reference to "libgstreamersharpglue-1.0.0.dll" or "libgstreamer-1.0-0.dll" error "a reference to could not be added please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component" is shown. I think it is because these are native libraries, so I added to my C# class something like this:
[DllImport("libgstreamersharpglue-1.0.0.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern void Init();
However Visual Studio whines at me something about not being able to load that function.

Comment: You need to have the native libraries along with the application. libgstreamersharpglue is compiled from generated.c and gobject.c, also read the comments in the link above.