# Building Vocaluxe on Windows using Visual Studio 2012 or Xamarin Studio on Windows

Tags: c#, mono, build-process, gstreamer

I want to build https://github.com/Vocaluxe/Vocaluxe/ on windows. I currently have installed mono-3.2.3 with gtksharp-2.12.11, howerver I can't build that project neither on Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 nor on Xamarin studio.

When Vacaluxe is opened in Visual Studio 2012, two warning messages appear instantly. Visual Studio complains that: 1) The referenced component 'SlimDX' could not be found and 2) The referenced component 'System.Data.SQLite' could not be found. As a result build fails.

When I open that project in Xamarin Studio error message pops up, saying that "Could not load Visual C++ project 'GstreamerHelper\GstreamerHelper.vcxproj'. This project type is not supported by Xamarin studio". GstreamerHelper package has red icon and on the right side "Load failed" is written, however remaining packages "PartyModeChallenge", "PartyModeChallengeMedley", "PartyModeTicTacToe", "ServerLib", "Vocaluxe" etc. seems to be fine. Building process fails on this IDE too.

How can I build this program on windows? What steps do I need to take in order to get rid of these warning and error messages in IDEs?

P.S
I'm curious about this because I want to create my own gstreamer 1.0 C# bindings project on windows.

Comment: Well it seems like Vocaluxe is build with Visual Studio, since it has some C++ projects contained. I'm currently also looking how to get the gstreamer-sharp binding to run on windows and linux, but I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 0):

SlimDX can be downloaded from http://slimdx.org/ while System.Data.SQLite can be downloaded from https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

If possible, contact the developer of Vocaluxe to see how you should grab the dependencies.

Obviously this project must be edited and built in Visual Studio (due to vcxproj). You cannot use Xamarin Studio.