# Is it possible to run gstreamer 1.0 "sharp" bindings using .Net C# in visual studio on windows or is it just for mono and linux only?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, mono, gstreamer

Is it possible to run gstreamer 1.0 "sharp" bindings using .Net C# in MS Visual studio 2012 on windows or is it just for mono and linux only?

I ask this, because it is unable to build gstreamer-sharp-0.99.0 "sharp" bindings for gstreamer 1.0 on windows, what is more there is an information on the official site http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/bindings/ that there are no offcial .Net bindings. Does that mean that current gstreamer-sharp version is for mono and linux only? Please explain this.

Comment: Have you looked into compiling Banshee for Windows? As fas as I know there have been Windows releases and it uses GStreamer. http://banshee.fm/download/development/#windows

Comment: I have gstreamer up and running, however I need gstreamer bindings for .Net C# and these bindings doesn't seem to work on windows. I need someone to tell me whether is it possible to run gstreamer sharp bindings on .Net C#.

Comment: Banshee is a C# media player so it should have the bindings in its build source. Testing if the Windows build works would probably be a good first step. The main target for Banshee is Linux so the Windows build might be outdated. I am running a Mac and the space on my Parallels drive is running out so unfortunately I cannot revisit the Banshee Windows build (but might try to build it for Mac).

Comment: Yes it's possible, see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577733/how-to-build-gstreamer-sharp-with-monodevelop-xamarin/21607884#21607884