# Gstreamer-sharp.dll run under linux (mono)

Tags: c#, linux, dll, mono, gstreamer

I'm coming from here: [How to build gstreamer-sharp with monodevelop/xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577733/how-to-build-gstreamer-sharp-with-monodevelop-xamarin)

I managed to build my application with gstreamer under .net. Now I tried the first start with mono, and it crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
[sven@localhost AudioCuesheetEditor-linux-v1.1.3]$ sh AudioCuesheetEditor
AudioCuesheetEditor: Zeile 2: $'\r': Kommando nicht gefunden.
Missing method .ctor in assembly /usr/lib/mono/gac/gtk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gtk-sharp.dll, type GLib.IgnoreClassInitializersAttribute
Can't find custom attr constructor image: /usr/lib/mono/gac/gtk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gtk-sharp.dll mtoken: 0x0a000131
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: libglib-2.0-0.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) GLib.Marshaller:g_malloc (uintptr)
  at GLib.Marshaller.StringToPtrGStrdup (System.String str) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.Global.set_ProgramName (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gtk.Application.SetPrgname () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gtk.Application.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at AudioCuesheetEditor.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[sven@localhost AudioCuesheetEditor-linux-v1.1.3]$ sh AudioCuesheetEditor
AudioCuesheetEditor: Zeile 2: $'\r': Kommando nicht gefunden.

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
```

I already started a gstreamer-sharp.dll.config with the following input:

```
<configuration>
  <dllmap os="linux" dll="libgstreamer-1.0-0.dll" target="libgstreamer-1.0.so.0"/>
</configuration>
```

But what is missing there? Why doesnt he find glib?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Greeting
Sven

Comment: what version of gstreamer-sharp are you using?

Comment: Version 0.99.x, currently the build dll from Vocadeluxe.

Answer (score 0):

GStreamerSharp 0.99.x is only compatible with gtk-sharp-3, not gtk-sharp-2.

You're trying to force it to run with gtk-sharp2, and at runtime it's throwing this error:

```
Missing method .ctor in assembly /usr/lib/mono/gac/gtk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gtk-sharp.dll, type GLib.IgnoreClassInitializersAttribute
```

Link it with gtk-sharp3 and you'll be fine.

Comment: Ok, but I thought gtk-sharp-2 and gtk-sharp-3 are paralell installable?! I use gtk-sharp-2 for for GUI, so I would need to get the application to run under gtk-sharp-3 first?

Comment: The answer to both of your questions is yes

Comment: Well, why? Sorry, if ask a bit uncomfortable, but why does gstreamer-sharp run under windows with gtk-sharp 2.12.x and on linux not?

Comment: I'm not sure how you got the idea that GStreamerSharp 0.99.x runs in Windows with gtk-sharp2? You are probably talking about an old version of GStreamerSharp (the 0.10 version, which mapped to GStreamer 0.10.x?)

Comment: Ok, let me explain what I did, so I hope you can say me, what I'm doing wrong ;). I took the gstreamer-sharp.dll from https://github.com/Vocaluxe/Vocaluxe/tree/develop/Output, linked it to my project, added the glib-sharp.dll from there, installed gstreamer 1.2.2 and could use gstreamer for playing sound on windows. The project is build with xamarin studio and linked against gtk-sharp-2.12.x. Maybe I got gtk3 on my system, but the project is not linked against it. So I thought, it runs on windows with gtk-sharp-2.12.x?!

Comment: ok, the key step is when you copied glib-sharp.dll -> that is glib-sharp 3.0.0.0 (from gtk-sharp3), not glib-sharp 2.12.0.0. That is the step you're missing to do in Linux the same.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But I copied the glib-sharp.dll also into the normal program folder, so that mono could load it. Or do I need to say mono explicitly, to use this dll? I'm really sorry, if ask too much, but I'm not that familiar with the gtk-sharp,glib-sharp and gstreamer-sharp bindings :(.

Comment: glib-sharp 3.0 is not compatible with gtk-sharp 2.0, end of story

Comment: Ok, and on windows there is no gtk-sharp involved, or why does it work on windows?!

Comment: I don't know, you can try to figure out for yourself how the hell that unsupported scenario works in one platform and not for the other, I will not help you with that though

Comment: @knocte hello! Please check my [question about gstreamer-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35122259/gstreamer-sharp-for-android), thanks!