# Turn a Windows Phone into a video streaming server using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, video-streaming, webrtc, rtsp

I want to stream video **from** a Windows Phone 8/8.1 device but I'm not sure where to start.  I have done extensive web searching for C# examples or libraries to do this but everything I have found so far covers using the phone as a *client*, not as a *source*.

I'm guessing I need to turn the phone into an RTSP server? If not, what is the correct technique or starting point for doing this?  Main concerns are that the streaming be smooth and with minimal lag, since the Windows Phone (camera) is mounted on a robot for remote navigation.  Too much lag or video performance problems and navigation will be impossible.  Any libraries or samples that show how to do this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since this is an almost link only answer, It'll be a comment: Have you had a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371955/Motion-JPEG-Streaming-Server ?

Comment: Gstreamer has some good C# bindings(you also need the compiled native dlls) but I am not sure that the source can be compiled on windows phone(I know it works on windows 8.1 but I am not 100% sure if there are slight differences). And Gstreamer has a good Rtsp server solution.

Comment: I've used VideoLAN DotNet (https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet) to great effect as a video streaming server. VLC exists for Windows Phone and it may be possible to reference that from VideoLAN DotNet.
GStreamer 1.0 has the lowest latency I've observed (sub-100ms) for real time streaming over wifi, but I cannot for love nor money get the bindings to work (0.10 bindings exist, 1.0 bindings don't quite - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577733/how-to-build-gstreamer-sharp-with-monodevelop-xamarin).
Have you considered just using a Raspberry Pi and camera module? *Much* easier!

Comment: @goobering Re: raspberry Pi.  Robot only supports smart phone.  Would have to build custom case, audio jack hookup, and more to duplicate.  Not worth it at this point.