# How Do I Stream Audio To Speakers In C#

Tags: c#, arrays, audio, stream, byte

I want to be able to stream a byte array directly to my speakers so that I can create sound.

I don't know where to begin.

Is it a DLL import or a memory stream?

What I want to send an array like this:

```
byte[] bt = {12,32,43,74,23,53,24,54,234,253,153};// example array
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`SoundPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) and play from a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx):

```
byte[] bt = {12,32,43,74,23,53,24,54,234,253,153};// example array
var ms = new MemoryStream(bt);
var sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
sound.Stream = ms;
sound.Play();
```

Comment: I guess one needs to construct a WAV file as bytes for this? (+1)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152034/convert-short-to-stream-which-can-be-played-as-audio) is an example of a memory stream that automatically makes the WAV header for you.